# Groovy exception

Tags: groovy, jira

Please help. I can't understand whats wrong with my script.

```
import org.apache.log4j.Category
import com.atlassian.jira.ComponentManager
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.jql.builder.JqlQueryBuilder
import com.atlassian.jira.event.type.EventDispatchOption
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.MutableIssue
import java.util.Date
import java.util.Calendar
import com.atlassian.jira.bc.JiraServiceContextImpl
import com.atlassian.jira.web.bean.PagerFilter
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue
import java.util.List
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueInputParameters
import com.atlassian.jira.user.util.UserManager
import com.atlassian.jira.user.ApplicationUser
import com.atlassian.crowd.embedded.api.CrowdService
import com.atlassian.crowd.embedded.api.User


def Category log = Category.getInstance("com.onresolve.jira.groovy.PostFunction")
log.setLevel(org.apache.log4j.Level.DEBUG)

def user = ComponentAccessor.getJiraAuthenticationContext().getLoggedInUser()
def ctx = new JiraServiceContextImpl(user)
def searchRequestService = ComponentManager.getInstance().getSearchRequestService()
def searchProvider = ComponentManager.getInstance().getSearchProvider()
def sr = searchRequestService.getFilter(ctx, 17540)
def searchResult = searchProvider.search(sr?.getQuery(), user, PagerFilter.getUnlimitedFilter())
def issueManager = ComponentManager.getInstance().getIssueManager()
def issues = searchResult.getIssues().collect {issueManager.getIssueObject(it.id)}


for ( issue in issues ){
    issueInputParameters issueToCreate = ComponentAccessor.getIssueService().newIssueInputParameters();
    issueToCreate.setSummary("This is a test.");
    issueToCreate.setDescription("Testing issue creation");
    issueToCreate.setAssigneeId(user.getName());
    issueService.createValidationResult validationResult = ComponentAccessor.getIssueService().validateCreate(user, issueToCreate);
    if(!validationResult.isValid()){
         for(String registeredErrorMessage:validationResult.getErrorCollection().getErrors().values())
         {
              printx "Failed"
         }
    }
    else {
        issueService.issueResult createdIssue = ComponentAccessor.getIssueService().create(user, validationResult);
    }
}
return issues
```

I get the next excetpion :

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>   org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.issueInputParameters()
>   is applicable for argument types:
>   (com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueInputParametersImpl) values:
>   [com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueInputParametersImpl@6cde0354]  at
>   Script87.run(Script87.groovy:34)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't the `issueInputParameters` in this line be capitialized - `IssueInputParameters`:

```
issueInputParameters issueToCreate =  ComponentAccessor.getIssueService().newIssueInputParameters();
```